# Xamarin forms list view with headers

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to do a list view
with 4 headers

however when I run my code it crashed.
I am sure there something with my Xaml I am doing wrong would be happy
for some help
and for a code example thanks

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewm">
            <ListView.Header  BackgroundColor="#ffa63c95">
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="תאריך" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="3"  TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium" BackgroundColor="#ffa63c95"/>
                        <Label Text="שעת התחלה" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="2" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium" BackgroundColor="#ffa63c95"/>
                        <Label Text="שעת סיום" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium" BackgroundColor="#ffa63c95"/>
                        <Label Text="שם האירוע" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium" BackgroundColor="#ffa63c95"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ListView.Header>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text ="Barak" ></TextCell>
                        <TextCell Text ="Barak" ></TextCell>
                        <TextCell Text ="Barak" ></TextCell>
                    <TextCell Text ="Barak" ></TextCell>
                </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>            


  public MainPage(Conferance conferance,string userPhone)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        List<string> ls = new List<string>();
        ls.Add("sa");
        ls.Add("s");
        listViewm.ItemsSource = ls ;
   }
```

Comment: you can't use multiple cells in a template

Comment: OK so what I can do? in order to perform 4 columns? with a header?

Comment: try using a ViewCell containing a Grid instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Xaramin Forms does not have good error messages.  If many case it throws an indecipherable exception rather than producing a meaning error message.

Here is what you need for your item template...

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Text ="Barak" ></Label>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text ="Barak" ></Label>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text ="Barak" ></Label>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text ="Barak" ></Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```